# Clear text field do not empty the input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I'm sure I'm missing something really small but I just couldn't fine it!
I'm trying to clean the text input, I'm setting the state to ('') and it's clearing the variable but the HTML input keep the old value...

What am I missing??
https://codesandbox.io/s/cleartextfield-su3y9

Thanks for the helpers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed missing something really small :)
Please add `value={searchValue}` as a prop for the `TextField` component.

Answer (score 0):

checkout https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled

Your component isn't controlled.

`TextField` has a `value` prop.

Setting `value={searchValue}` will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to pass in the value prop to the TextField component

https://codesandbox.io/s/cleartextfield-wppk4?from-embed